# ConcurrentModificationException in Firebase for DynamiteModulesC

Tags: android, firebase, google-play

Android app is in production and we are getting this error since the version `10.2.0` of firebase and google-play. The update did help us.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncaught exception in Firebase Database runloop (3.0.0). Please report to firebase-database-client@google.com
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbnv$1$1.run(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
       at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.remove(HashMap.java:806)
       at bok.l(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:661)
       at bok.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:401)
       at bny.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:82)
       at bny.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:14087)
       at bpb.c(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:319)
       at bpk.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:3309)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:154)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Libraries:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.2.1'
```

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Could you take a look please